# How to login to a website through android

Tags: android, http-post

I need to login to a website programmatically through an Android app, for example Gmail. I'm new to android and java so I don't really know much about this. I have made a layout with two edittexts for username and password and one button for login. I need to be able to login into Gmail using this, without actually displaying the website.
Here's my code so far:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    String MY_ACC = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
    String MY_PASS = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
    String TAG = "MainActivity";

    String GMAIL_LOGIN = "https://mail.google.com";

  try {  DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(GMAIL_LOGIN);

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", MY_ACC));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Passwd", MY_PASS));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("signIn", "Sign in"));

    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


}
   catch (Exception e) {

  }
```

Note that I have surrounded the code in a try-catch block and right now, I've just set it to catch any exception.

Thanks in advance!